# Center of mass of $4z^2=x^2+y^2$ within $x=0, y=0, z=0, z=3$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have a solid limited by the cone: $4z^2=x^2+y^2$ and the following planes: $x=0, y=0, z=0, z=3$

This solid has a density = $1$

I already found the volume using the following triple integral ($r$ referring to radius):

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{6}\int_{\sqrt{r^2/4}}^{3} r dz dr d\theta =9\pi$$

From that, what would be the best way to find the moment of inertia and finally the center of mass / barycenter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\verb*a^{2}*\ \mbox{yields}\ a^{2}$.

Comment: What is your aim, to find center of mass? Your title says so but you also mention moment of inertia in the body.

Comment: Are you assuming constant density?

Answer (score 1):

The cone is symmetric for x and y .Z is the symmetry axis of the cone. It is comparable with revolving an isosceles triangle about z. The height of cone is from 0 t0 3 i.e, $h=3$ so the center of mass will have a distance
$\frac23 h=2$ from the vertex of the cone . The coordinates of this point is $C (0, 0, 2).$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the volume in the first quadrant is one-quarter that of the whole cone, i.e. $\frac14\cdot \frac13\cdot 3 \cdot (\pi \cdot6^2)= 9\pi$. Then, the coordinates of its barycenter are

$$z_c =\frac1{9\pi}\int_0^3 \int_0^{2z} \int_0^{\frac\pi2}z \>r dr d\theta dz=\frac94
$$

$$x_c=y_c =\frac1{9\pi}\int_0^3 \int_0^{2z} \int_0^{\frac\pi2}
r\cos\theta \> rdr d\theta dz=\frac6\pi
$$